# Rename 'timeseries' objects by command line in Matlab

Tags: matlab, simulation, simulink

After doing a simulation in Simulink, via the To Workspace block, I got a 'timeseries' object. For example, its name is 'xx'.
Now, can I change its name in the workspace by command line? (Without right click and rename).
Thank you so much!

Comment: is `xx=timeseries;` fine?

Comment: As per @Yotam's answer, changing the name of a variable is trivial.  But why not just get the block to create the variable with the name you want rather than `xx`?

Comment: Because I do a lot of simulation in the same simulation file and in each file I have a lot of timeseries object, Therefore I want to write a script that can change the timeseries name for each simulation.

Answer (score 0):

If 'xx' is the object name, you can simply:

```
newname=xx;
clear xx;
```

Remember 'timeseries' is the **type** of the object, so it cannot be assigned into a variable name.

Comment: Dear @Yotam, my idea is impossible in Matlab Simulink?